# Phone doesn't power up while charging, cannot unbrick because of this

Tags: clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking

I've got a LG Optimus L7 which is in a bricked state because of a failed ClockworkMod upgrade some months ago.

I am trying make it work again, but I cannot undergo the process of unbricking since the phone does not get past the LG logo when connected to power. This is true when its battery is removed and for when it's not.

The only way that it doesn't get stuck at the LG logo phase is when I hold the volume up key while connecting it to power, but that only boots to emergency mode, which is used for step 1 of the unbricking process. For step 2 of the KDZ LG phone update, it needs to boot in non-emergency mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it software bricked or hardware bricked . It is easy to unbrick software bricked phone but for hardware bricked phone you have to contact service centre.

Comment: I am pretty sure it's software, that's why I am trying to unbrick. The bricking happened after a failed Clockwork mod update.